# How can I get insight in what the control plane does in K8s?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, trace

I am getting started with Kubernetes. I would like to get insight into what exactly the control plane does. To do this, I used [stern](https://github.com/wercker/stern) with the query `stern . -n kube-system`. This trails all logs of the `kube-system`.

The output is quite underwhelming. Can I somehow increase the log-level to trace? Are there other ways to get more insight into the control plane?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve and why? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I know what each component in the control plane does in theory. I now want to witness that in the real world. For that I am using stern to follow the logs, but I almost get no log output. Is there a way to tell K8s to be verbose? Or is there a different way to get a better live, in-depth understanding of K8s

Comment: Do you actually want to see the verbose logs of k8s controlplane pods or do you want to see all the requests going through apiserver? First one can be achieved by adding --v=10 flag to all controlplain pods, second can be achieved by configuring [audit log](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/).